# How can I resolve unreadable text within Dolphin in Ubuntu?

Tags: filemanager, dolphin

I'm trying out Dolphin within Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm finding that half of the rows within the details view are essentially unreadable because they have black text atop a black background. Is there any way to resolve this? I prefer using a dark theme, so I'd like to make all rows black and change the text color to white. However, any solution that makes the text more readable would be appreciated.

[image: Unreadable text within Dolphin]

Comment: looks like the theming for kde (qt) apps is a bit wonky, see [this q&a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591308/how-to-set-dark-theme-for-kde-apps-on-xubuntu) with some ideas of how to change it

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this! I was able to resolve the issue by installing the Flatpak version of Dolphin, but I'll keep this in mind if I encounter any other issues with the file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by installing the Flatpak version of Dolphin 23.04.02 instead. I did so by going to Software, searching for Dolphin, and choosing the Flathub (Flatpak) option instead of the Ubuntu (deb) option. The text was set to a lighter color by default, so I could read it without making any further adjustments or installing any other programs.

[image]